# Объединить файлы эксель, не открывая на питоне

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Так как у меня 8-10 этажные заголовки в файлах эксель, то хотелось бы объединить 2 файла( не открывая, чтобы не слетело форматирование) и записать их в третий(куда на третью страницу будет записываться датафрейм, полученный в результате работы программы). Возможно ли это на питоне?

Comment: получить содержимое файла, не читая это содержимое — задача, пожалуй невыполнимая в той реальности, что дана нам в ощущениях.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Наверное имелось в виду таки "не открывая экселем" или что-то вроде того )

Comment: Библиотека pandas хорошо работает с Excel файлами. 
В теории, с чтением проблем не должно быть, так как в опции чтения можно указать сколько рядов можно пропустить, то есть пропустить ваши форматированные заголовки. Стоит поискать в pandas вставку в определённый ряд, что бы в 3-м файле сохранить форматирование (то есть создать заранее файл с форматированием и уже пайтоном вставлять в определённый ряд данные), но я не могу гарантировать, что форматирование не будет нарушено, вам следует это протестировать.

Comment: @CrazyElf интересно участие в полугодовалом проекте в роли Data Scientist  ( прогнозирование популярности постов в соцсетях)? telegram aljona_Barbanova